# JSQMessageViewController textview does not display link

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

i am using jsqmessageviewcontroller for chat application.in my app when i send url link than does not display message as link but display as message i tried this code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell=nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    JSQMessage *msg = [self.arrChatMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
if ([msg.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]){
        cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.cellTopLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }else{
        cell.textView.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
        cell.cellTopLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    }
    cell.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : cell.textView.textColor,
                                          NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternSolid) };
    return cell;
}
```

here is my screenshot

[image]

Please help how can i solve this problem..

Comment: did you double check you not set dataDetectorTypes of collectionview's textview in anywhere

Comment: @Quoc Nguyen i have already set dataDetectorTypes in cellForItemAtIndexPath method in jsqmessage class